# How to encrypt pdf in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, itext

I want to add a Password on PDF I'm using itext for it

I have tried this code

```
public void encryptPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
            PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

But the app crashes and shows This Error

```
Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 0xcdeae5c1 in tid 20493 (sdifa.pdfreader), pid 20493 (sdifa.pdfreader)
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on? Do you have any stacktrace? Any info on which code exactly is at least in correlational relationship with the error?